# Website technologies

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm a sw engineer but I have almost zero experience in web development. I have noticed recently few interesting websites and I'm curious how they are built.
The first example is
http://www.google.com/nexus/5/
I'm really excited about the way page reacts when you get to the mid part where it describes the camera.
Today I saw that Microsoft has a similar website for their new CEO
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/news/ceo/index.html
Since this is Microsoft, I'm guessing that it uses completely different web technology.

So, my question is, if I were to build a website like this for myself, where would I start first? I'm guessing that Google's website is relying heavily on JavaScript, but are there any open libraries/frameworks that I could use to achieve this effect?

Comment: Search for the keyword **parallax**

Comment: If you are talking about visual cool stuff, you can have a look on Jquery.

Comment: No offense intended but your question is kind of like, I have no experience with cars but I recently saw a Lamborghini - can someone tell me how to build one from scratch?

Comment: @Conner no, my question is more like: "I know cars transport people and I just saw one flat, mean looking one, where can I find a dealer and get more information about it".

Comment: @Милан The design you are talking about is one page template, you can  see the demo of creative design at http://themeforest.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Parallax` scrolling for the scroll effects.

The `jQuery library` of `javascript` and of course using `HTML / CSS` for styling and structuring your pages. This is where you can start off.